# Caching Outputimages in OpenGLES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, egl

My Problem:

I have a video (with lets say 25FPS) that has to be rendered with opengles 2.0 on the screen.
For reading the video I use a decoder that decodes that video into opengl es textures. With a renderpass I draw this texture on the screen.

What I have to do is get the image from the decoder upload it to the gpu, call the shaderprogram and render the image on the screen. If the video has 25FPS I have to update the screen in 40ms steps (1000ms/25FPS).

In each step I have todo the following:

- get the image from the decoder
- push it to the gpu memory
- render the screen
- swap buffers

So far it is working.
Now it happens, that the decoder takes longer than 40ms to decode a frame. That does not happen all the time but sometimes.

A solution would be building a cache. Meaning, I do render i.e. 5 images, before showing the first. This comes with a problem, it has to happen asynchron, so the cache can be build and the screen be rendered at the same time. If that happens you can see that on the video because it is not "fluid" anymore.

My Question:

- Is there a solution for that?
- Is it possible to create a ?-buffer, that can be copied(?!) on the backbuffer of the rendersurface, so that I can create a cache with that kind of buffers, and copy that onto the backbuffer without blocking the other thread which is creating this buffers?

OR

- How to fill the backbuffer with another buffer?

I tried already:

- Rendering Framebuffer(Textures) as cache. This works almost perfect, except that the texture has to be rendered as well. This means that (because it's asynchron) if a cacheframe is build and the image for the screen is build, you have to mutex(/synchronize) the rendermethods, otherwise the program crashes. But syncrhonizing takes the whole point of doing it asynchron. So this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in OpenGL, if you do not clear and redraw the screen, the previous image will persist.  If a new frame is not ready in time, simply do nothing.

It sounds like you have two threads: one decoding frames, and one rendering them.  This is fine.

If render() is called and a new frame is not ready in time, your render method should return immediately.  Do not clear or swap buffers.  The screen will be preserved.

Now, the user /may/ notice occasional hiccups when a frame is repeated twice.  25 fps is an unnatural frame rate (OpenGL only supports 60/30/15/etc.), so it will not align perfectly to the screen refresh rate.

You could live with this (user likely won't notice).  Or you could force playback to 30 fps by buffering frames.

A good idea is to place a message queue between your decoder and your renderer.  It could be one or several frames deep.  It could be an array, linked list, or ring buffer.  This allows the decoder to upload into many cached textures while the rendering is drawing a different texture.

The decoder adds frames to the queue as they come in.  The renderer runs at a fixed rate (30 fps).  You could pause rendering until N frames have been buffered.

Comment: Clarification: using OpenGL ES from two threads can be tricky.  It "just works" for upload/draw (at least on iOS and Nvidia Tegra).

If your device won't allow this, you must wrap the OGL context in a mutex. Each thread would re-bind the context before calling OGL.

Tricks to keep things fast: 
. Test if context is bound to thread; only rebind when needed.
. Pre-allocate textures.
. Don't delete textures; re-use them.
. Decode directly into texture memory if your device allows (skip glTexSubImage2D).

Then decode thread calls at most 1 OGL method (texture upload). Contention will be low.